# How to double deref in C?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

Trying to double dereference and print them (TOP TWO ARE EXAMPLES):

```
printf ("a's value     = %d \n", a) ;

printf ("a's address   = %p \n", &a) ;


printf ("a_ptr_ptr deref'ed defer'ed =d% \n",
```

What would go after the  \n", for a_ptr_ptr deref'ed defer'ed

Answer (score 1):

If you want the address of the address of `a`, you're going to have to store `a`'s address in a pointer variable, and take the address of that.  But having done so, yes, you can double-dereference that pointer with `**`, and get `a`'s value back.  Something like this:

```
int a = 5;
int *ip = &a;
int **ipp = &ip;

printf("ipp = %p\n", ipp);
printf("*ipp = %p, ip = %p, &a = %p\n", *ipp, ip, &a);
printf("**ipp = %d, *ip = %d\n", **ipp, *ip);
```

Theoretically you can continue this as long as you like:

```
int ***ippp = &ipp;
int ****ipppp = &ippp;
int *****ippppp = &ipppp;
printf("*****ippppp = %d\n", *****ippppp);
```

But by now this is mostly a game; there's no practical use in a real C program for a 5-level pointer, and at some point (after 8 or 10 levels, I think) the compiler's allowed to say "All right, enough, game over!".